# Pasting ggplot objects horizontally

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, axis

I'm trying to paste 16 different plots into one with a common x axis

I successfully made, plot and paste the graphs individually with grid.draw()

But i haven't been able to transform the x axis in a continuous way or at least remove the space between each graph

i attach some code to illustrate how the graphs were made.

```
plot1 = ggplot(map_snp %>% filter( chr == chr[1] ), aes(x=POS)) + 
  geom_histogram( binwidth = 2,
                  col=palette[2],
                  fill=palette[2],
                  alpha = .2) +
  xlab("Chromosome 1") +
  ylab("SNP count") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, colour = "black"),
        text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size = 12),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))

par_plots <- list() 
for (i in list_par) {
  par_plots[[i]] = ggplot(map_snp %>% filter( chr == i ), aes(x=POS)) + 
    geom_histogram( binwidth = 2,
                    col= palette[3],
                    fill= palette[3],
                    alpha = .2) +
    xlab(paste0(i)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, colour = "black"),
          text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size = 12),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))
}
impar_plots <- list()
for (i in list_impar) {
impar_plots[[i]] = ggplot(map_snp %>% filter( chr == i ), aes(x=POS)) + 
    geom_histogram( binwidth = 2,
                    col= palette[2],
                    fill=palette[2],
                    alpha = .2) +
  xlab(paste0(i)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, colour = "black"),
        text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size = 12),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))
}

grid.newpage()
png(paste("./snp_map.png"),  width = 15*4.5, height = 8, res = 320, units = "cm", pointsize = 12, bg = "white")
grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(plot1),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 2`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 3`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 4`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 5`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 6`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 7`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 8`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 9`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 10`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 11`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 12`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 13`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 14`),
                ggplotGrob(impar_plots$`Chromosome 15`),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots$`Chromosome 16`),
                size = "last"))

dev.off()
```

SNP MAP

[image]

Comment: How are you looking to transform your x axis?  It already looks continuous and for what you've done so far, it would seem that this could be replicated via `facet_wrap()`.  Can you explain a bit what you are trying to accomplish and provide an example dataset that could be used alone to illustrate your question?  If your data is too large (as I guess it might be), can you demonstrate the same principle with one of the built-in datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get rid of most of the border, but not quiiiiite all. Here using an example from built in `diamonds` data set from `ggplot2`.

```
par_plots <- list() 
cuts = unique(diamonds$cut)
for (c in as.numeric(cuts)) {
  par_plots[[c]] = ggplot(diamonds %>% filter(as.numeric(cut) == c),
                          aes(x = price)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(0)) +
    xlab(paste0(i)) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, colour = "black"),
          text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size = 12), 
          plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))
}

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
# png(paste("./snp_map.png"),  width = 15*4.5, height = 8, res = 320, units = "cm", pointsize = 12, bg = "white")
grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(par_plots[[1]]),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots[[2]]),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots[[3]]),
                ggplotGrob(par_plots[[4]])))


dev.off()
```

[image]